# How to draw a Gaussian Curve with LibreOffice Draw?

Tags: libreoffice, vector-graphics, libreoffice-draw

I would like to draw a Gaussian curve as a vector graphic in LibreOffice Draw. With the "Curve" functions I was only able to get something  [parabola-like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io0ok.png)
Has anyone got an idea of how to do the Gaussian?

Thank you in advance!